# How to replace string with diffrent strings in list of file Notepad++

Tags: string, replace, notepad++

Hello I have a list of file 100 files .

each file contain

```
a = a & "blahblhablhablha"
a = a & "blahblhablhablha"
a = a & "blahblhablhablha"
a = a & "blahblhablhablha"
```

I want all files should be replaced like this

```
public file1
a1 = a1 & "blahblhablhablha"
a1 = a1 & "blahblhablhablha"
a1 = a1 & "blahblhablhablha"
a1 = a1 & "blahblhablhablha"
a1x = a1
end file
```

In file two it should be

```
public file2
a2 = a2 & "blahblhablhablha"
a2 = a2 & "blahblhablhablha"
a2 = a2 & "blahblhablhablha"
a2x = a2
end file
```

and soo on ... until last 100 file

lets say our last file looks like

```
public file100
a100 = a100 & "blahblhablhablha"
a100 = a100 & "blahblhablhablha"
a100 = a100 & "blahblhablhablha"
a100x = a100
end file
```

Comment: This would be a great task for a scripting language like python.  Not sure you'll be able to easily do this with Notepad++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You simply **can't** do that in Notepad++!

The reason is that you don't have access to the name of the file you edit nor to a counter of edited files when using regular expressions (and this is how you would edit the file in your case). In theory, it is possible to do it, by processing manually each file and hardcode the filename each time, but as jgritty suggested, the best thing to do is use a more appropriate tool, like sed, or Python, Perl etc.

#### So here's a Python solution to your problem:

```py
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile,join

path="yourfolder" #change it to your path of files

for filename in listdir(path): #read all entries from path
    if isfile(join(path,filename)): #keep only the files
        with open(join(getcwd(),path,filename),"r+") as file: #open each file
            num=filename #I assume that the files are named 1,...,100. If that's not the case then change this to a counter
            content=file.readlines() #pull the file contents
            content.insert(0,"public file%s\n" % num) #insert the 1st line
            content.append("a%sx = a%s\nend file\n" % (num,num)) #append the last lines
            file.seek(0) #reset file's current position in order to overwrite it
            for line in content:
                line=line.replace("a = a","a%s = a%s" % (num,num)) #edit the lines
                file.write(line) #write the output
```